# How do I block Google adsense linking to files on my server?

Tags: php

Today I noticed that a few Google advertisements in an adsence block on one of my pages were trying to display a file called "`/pagead/badge/checkout_999999.gif`" from my server. I did a bit of investigating and found out that the companies behind these adverts use Google Checkout and "`checkout_999999.gif`" is supposed to be a tiny shopping kart icon with a tooltip which reads "This site accepts Google Checkout".

My problem is that "`/pagead/badge/checkout_999999.gif`" doesn't exist on my server. What do you do to handle this on your website? e.g:

1. Save the logo ([image]) on your server in the place it is expected by Google?
2. Use a mod_rewrite rule to redirect the request? To where though?
3. Find a adsense option to turn off Google checkout enabled adverts? (I looked but couldn't see one?)
4. Ignore the issue and get on with something important

---

*Back-story - **please ignore unless very bored:*** Page 2 of the [search page](http://www.peopleperhour.com/find.php) on our site suddenly stopped working and I didn't know why. It turned out to be related to Google adsense. We use PHP session variables to save search criteria over different pages which worked fine for a while but then randomly stopped working. *Random bugs are the worst!* I was trying to work out what else is random on the page and decided that the Google ads were the only other random thing. Sure enough, sometimes a particular advert seemed to clear the session variables and break the search. What was actually happening was that the advert was requesting a image from our server ("`checkout_999999.gif`") which didn't exist and Apache was behind-the-scenes redirecting to the site homepage which unfortunately clears the session variables needed for the search - hence the non-obvious breakage. I'm a bit worried that Google ads can request random files from my sever? I'd prefer if they could only use absolute URL's if they want to include logo's or other media.

Comment: I admire your self control for not making up your own checkout_999999.gif image.  :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it (and actually started setting about doing it) but then realised that I'd actually only be de-facing my own site! :-)

Comment: Your server should be sending a 404 for that non-existent file, not redirecting. If you fix the server, that should fix your problem.

Comment: +1 for realizing this is a problem and reporting it, many would have just created the image.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Adsense administration/handling/bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with Apache `mod_rewrite` for a while I have found a rule that seems to fix my Google Adsense issue:

```
RewriteRule ^\/pagead\/badge\/checkout\_999999\.gif$ http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/badge/checkout_999999.gif [R=301,L]
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to stop a similar thing happening in the future if Google decides to hotlink to a different file?

Comment: you should file a bug with Google.  that icon should had an absolute URL

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a bug with google adsense delivery. File a bug with them is your best bet for a long-term fix.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, bug filed (https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/topic.py?topic=8424)

Comment: +1, a lot of people would just have created the image while the bug remains unreported.

Answer (score 1):

As Google doesn't care about the problem (previous posts were sent in June and we are now in October... and the bug was reported directely to Google), I decided to put an image on my server that would suggest the user to click on the ad!

Clicks then increased!!

As this is my server, I can do what I want and that's not my problem if Google asks for files on my server. They cost me money by using my bandwidth and connecting to my server, I am now paid for that!!

You should do the same...

Comment: Clever idea :-) Do you have a URL I can see?